# NSLog InterfaceRotation doesn't work on simulator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I want to know why there´s no console output when testing on the iOS simulator by tracing that code in my UIViewController - it only traces by testing on a device.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    NSLog(@"willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: ", toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

And how do i print out that UIInterfaceOrientation value (type of enum)? 
Would be great to get your help on that..Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Where is your format specifier?

`UIInterfaceOrientation` is a `typedef enum`, not an object, so you cannot use `%@` as the format specifier.

Should look like this:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
   NSLog(@"willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: %d", toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

If you ***really*** need this kind of "pretty print" functionality, you can run it through a `switch`, like this:

```
NSString *orient;
switch(toInterfaceOrientation) {
   case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
       orient = @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight";
       break;
   case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
       orient = @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft";
       break;
   case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
       orient = @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait";
       break;
   case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
       orient = @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown";
       break;
   default: 
       orient = @"Invalid orientation";
}
NSLog(@"willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: %@", orient);
```

Comment: yeah, thanks for your really fast answer! How do i print out that UIInterfaceOrientation-value?

Comment: The code does just that. It is a numerical value - you need to query the docs for the translation.